# Printing Current Method in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, reflection, methods

How do I print the name of the method I am in, in Objective-C?

In Java/C# I could do this using reflection. Is similar possible with Objective-C?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For just printing method name, use

```
NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromSelector(_cmd));
```

To printing method arguments is a complex task.
every message in ObjectiveC is converted to `objMsgSend (id self, SEL, arg0...)`
We need to walk through stack, and print them out, as we see after _cmd + sizeof(SEL) will give us address to arg0 (but the size and type for arg0 is unknown).

```
Method method = class_getInstanceMethod([self class], _cmd);
unsigned nargs = method_getNumberOfArguments(method);
void *start = _cmd;
for(unsigned i = 0; i< nargs ; i++) {
  char *argtype = method_copyArgumentType(method, i);
  //find arg size from argtype
  // walk stack given arg zie
  free(argtype);
}
```

Basic implementations should look like this.

So if the arguments are objects, that will be great (as we know the size of argument are 32/64 bit). Otherwise we need to do type encoding, and move cursor by argument's size. Have look https://github.com/holtwick/HOLog , that does exactly what you want, but it works under Simulator only.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks. Is there a variant of that for printing method arguments too?

Comment: @GauravSharma I will try to do it, and will give you know.